# Plotting surf plot into axes object in GUI from .m-file

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

I am a little lost... I have an .m file that plots a surf plot into a figure repetitively with a hold and a "draw now" so as to create an animation.

I have now created a GUI (tag: 'GUI') with guide to set parameters for the simulation. After setting the parameters within the GUI and pressing a button I want the simulation to start as before, but instead of printing to the figure I want it to print to an axes object (tag: 'GUI_panel_plot_axes_fullframe') within the GUI now.

How do I go about accessing the axes object in my GUI from within my .m file? I have tried the following without success:

```
h = findobj('Tag','GUI');
handles = guihandles(h);
axes(handles.GUI_panel_plot_axes_fullframe);
```

However, I get an error when trying to access the handles object which should include my handle to my axes object:

```
Error using guihandles
H must be the handle to a figure or figure descendent.
```

I am open to changing the way how I access the handle around... I have already tried multiple versions roaming about the internet, but haven't had any luck with any of them! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you only have ONE figure with 'GUI' tag? And are you sure it is open? Try `handles = guihandles(h(1));`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell you the error without seing the rest of your code. 
Anyway, this is a example of a very simple GUI created with "guide". As you can see when you press the button and image is plotted into the axes called "axes1". I think you can get the idea.

```
function varargout = untitled(varargin)
    % UNTITLED MATLAB code for untitled.fig
    %      UNTITLED, by itself, creates a new UNTITLED or raises the existing
    %      singleton*.
    %
    %      H = UNTITLED returns the handle to a new UNTITLED or the handle to
    %      the existing singleton*.
    %
    %      UNTITLED('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
    %      function named CALLBACK in UNTITLED.M with the given input arguments.
    %
    %      UNTITLED('Property','Value',...) creates a new UNTITLED or raises the
    %      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
    %      applied to the GUI before untitled_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
    %      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
    %      stop.  All inputs are passed to untitled_OpeningFcn via varargin.
    %
    %      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
    %      instance to run (singleton)".
    %
    % See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

    % Edit the above text to modify the response to help untitled

    % Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 23-Feb-2018 14:39:54

    % Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
    gui_Singleton = 1;
    gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                       'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                       'gui_OpeningFcn', @untitled_OpeningFcn, ...
                       'gui_OutputFcn',  @untitled_OutputFcn, ...
                       'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                       'gui_Callback',   []);
    if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
        gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
    end

    if nargout
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    else
        gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    end
    % End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


    % --- Executes just before untitled is made visible.
    function untitled_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    % This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
    % hObject    handle to figure
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    % varargin   command line arguments to untitled (see VARARGIN)

    % Choose default command line output for untitled
    handles.output = hObject;

    % Update handles structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);

    % UIWAIT makes untitled wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
    % uiwait(handles.figure1);


    % --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
    function varargout = untitled_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
    % varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
    % hObject    handle to figure
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % Get default command line output from handles structure
    varargout{1} = handles.output;


    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
    function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    imshow('peppers.png','Parent',handles.axes1);
```